# I accentally removed a loopback device

Tags: drive, cd, devices, floppy

I accendentally removed /dev/loop2 and i need it for a "loopback-floppy" but everytime i try to do ANYTHING it just says: "mount: image.flp: failed to setup loop device: wrong ioctl() for device" and the same if i put in a floppy or cd.

i would prefer NOT to re-install

Comment: Why don't you create a blockdevice /dev/loop2? Oh and /dev/ should be recreated on EVERY reboot. Is does not recreate /dev/loop2??

Comment: cp /dev/loop /dev/loop2 output: cp: can not get status of '/dev/loop' , file does not exist and i am downloading something big so i would rather not reboot now

Comment: Rinzwind his answer worked, but now i also get: Error erasing device: doing BLKGETSIZE64 iotctl on /dev/sdb: Inapproprate ioctl for device (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Comment: @Rinzwind If you want to tag someone, you need to put a `@` before their name!

Comment: You can't copy devices like that! As indicated by @Rinzwind you have to use tools to create the devices. That said, `mount -o loop foo.img /mnt/foobar` seems to set up loopdevices automagically for me.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: I want to erase a disk but now it says: "Error erasing device: doing BLKGETSIZE64 iotctl on /dev/sdb: Inapproppiate ioctl for device (udisks-error-quark, 0)"

Comment: what does that have to do with the loop device?

Comment: Maybe you knew the answer so i didnt have to open another question

Comment: I fixed the problem doing: 1. pick up the floppy 2. smash it against the wall    3. retry 4. IT WORKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreate it with:

```
sudo -i
mknod /dev/loop2 b 7 2
chown --reference=/dev/loop0 /dev/loop2
chmod --reference=/dev/loop0 /dev/loop2
```

Comment: Bonus: `mknod` has a `--mode` option.